# How to install XGBoost or LightGBM on Windows?

Tags: python, xgboost, algorithms, windows

I'm a Windows user and would like to use those mentioned algorithms in the title with my Jupyter notebook which is a part of Anaconda installation.

I've tried in anaconda promt window:

```
pip install xgboost
```

which retuned:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement xgboost (from
>   versions: ) No matching distribution found for xgboost

Likewise, I've tried:

```
conda install lightgbm
```

which returned:

> Solving environment: failed
>
> CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url
>   https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch/repodata.json.bz2 Elapsed: -

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this XGBoost installation guide: https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html

If you are using python3 then make sure that you run: pip3 install xgboost

To fix the problem with lightgbm on windows try installing OpenSSL first, refer this: https://www.cloudinsidr.com/content/how-to-install-the-most-recent-version-of-openssl-on-windows-10-in-64-bit/n

Answer (score 2):

For anaconda you can install py-xgboost with:

> conda install -c anaconda py-xgboost

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing XGBoost as per the official [guide](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#) as well as the steps detailed [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/jfp/entry/Installing_XGBoost_For_Anaconda_on_Windows?lang=en). Unfortunately I could make neither work on My windows 10 64 bit machine.

What worked for me is to install it to anaconda's [py-xgboost package](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/py-xgboost).